# css margin between Responsive Top Navigation and page content

Tags: html, css

I have a Responsive Top Navigation bar modeled from w3schools. Below that, I have various pages.
In the div, I have to specify a margin-top. The problem is when I resize the screen width, the menu goes to (2) lines. I can not figure out how to move the page content down to keep the same spacing between the menu and the page.

Comment: Good to add any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the top nav bar is positioned absolute. The absolute will make the top bar in a new layer. So the content is not moving down when top bar is in two lines. You can try removing the position absolute if the top bar has that style.

Comment: That did not help. 
Originally, I tried using @media but it was not working for me. I played around with it some more and it looks like I got it to work. Hopefully, this is the correct technique.